# Issues with @ManyToMany hibernate mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I am new to web development. I have been trying to make an e commerce platform and using `@ManyToMany` mapping between `product` and `wishlist` using `wishlist_product` as the joining table.

Upon adding, I am not facing error, but the data is not been added in the join table. I have been trying to resolve this issue for 2 days now, but have been facing continuous failure. I have attached the code for both, `wishlist` and `product` below.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "wishlist")
public class Wishlist {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    /*
     * @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
     * 
     * @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters
     * = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "login"))
     */
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "wishlist_product", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private List<Electronics> product;
```

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "electronics")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "product_Type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Electronics {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "CamIdGenerator", strategy = "com.virtusa.neuralhack.vlx.IdGenerator.CameraIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CamIdGenerator")
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String productId;

    private String askingPrice;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private String howOld;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    transient private String email;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
    private User_Login user;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "wishlist_product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
    private List<Wishlist> wishlist;
```

```java
public void addToWishlist(String email, String productId) {

    Session currentSession = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Wishlist wishlist = currentSession.get(Wishlist.class,email);
        
    //System.out.println(wishlist.getUser());
        
    Electronics product = currentSession.get(Electronics.class, productId);
    System.out.println(product);

    wishlist.addToWishlist(product);
        
    //product.addAWishlist(wishlist);
    //System.out.println(wishlist.getProduct().get(0));

    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(wishlist);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you in the read-write transaction but not read-only.

And some advises:

- do not use the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` with the many-to-many association due to `CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.REMOVE` that in the case of many-to-many leads to too many entities are removed
- use Set instead of List for to-many association when you don't need specific order.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I introduced @Transactional annotation on my add to wishlist method, and it worked for me like a charm...

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "wishlist")
public class Wishlist {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "wishlist_product", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private List<Electronics> products;
    
    public void addProduct(Electronics product) {
       products.add( product );
       product.getWishlists().add( this );
    }

    public void removeProduct(Electronics product) {
      products.remove( product );
      product.getWishlists().remove( this );
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "electronics")
public class Electronics {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "product_id")
   private String productId;
   
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
   private List<Wishlist> wishlists;
}
```

1. Only an owning side of the [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional) `@ManyToMany` should be mapped by the `@JoinTable` annotation. You should use the `mappedBy` on the other side.
2. You should set `cascade` property on the owning side if you want to propagate persistent and other states.
3. To preserve synchronicity between both sides, it’s good practice to provide helper methods for adding or removing child entities.

And your `addToWishlist` method will look like this:

```java
public void addToWishlist(String email, String productId) {
   Session currentSession = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
   Wishlist wishlist = currentSession.get(Wishlist.class,email);
   Electronics product = currentSession.get(Electronics.class, productId);
   wishlist.addProduct(product);
   currentSession.saveOrUpdate(wishlist);
}
```

Comment: Hii @SternK , I tried the above steps but the result is still the same. Should I attach more code for referrence?

Comment: Tried changing the joinColumns and inverseJoinColumns aslo, but the result has not changed...

Comment: I would suggest you to enable hibernate properties `hibernate.show_sql` , `hibernate.format_sql`, `hibernate.use_sql_comments` and see what exactly sql hibernate executes. I tested the above mapping and it works for me.

Comment: Hey Stern, thanks for helping me out all the way. Other than the changes you suggested, I was missing out on putting the @Transactional annotation on my service class method. It now works perfectly... Thank You :)